# DECODE In Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use DECODE in PL/SQL statement (for sample HR schema)
but I got this error:

''The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned''

*This statement got a DEPARTMENT_ID from the user , compare it with a decode section, and shows where is that department located.*

```
declare
    v_dep varchar2(30);
    v_User_Input number(4):=&EnterLocID;
begin
    select decode(v_User_Input,10,'Seattle',
                                20,'Toronto',
                                30,'Toronto',
                                40,'London',
                                50,'South San Francisco',
                                60,'Southlake',
                                70,'Munich',
                                80,'Oxford',
                                90,'Toronto',
                                'else' )into v_dep from locations l,departments d
    where v_User_Input = d.department_id;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_dep);
end;
/
```

Comment: The behaviour of this query will the same in plain SQL as it is in a PL/SQL block, so I am not sure what PL/SQL has to do with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I see it, you *forgot* to join `LOCATIONS` and `DEPARTMENTS` tables so they are cross-joined, and then you applied a filter to `D.DEPARTMENT_ID`. However, there's a possibility that query still returns 2 or more rows which can't fit into a scalar `V_DEP` variable.

Therefore, this is what you might need to do (I don't have your tables so I can't test it, but I hope you'll get the idea):

```
FROM locations l join departments d on d.location_id = l.location_id
WHERE l.location_id = v_User_Input
```

Also, as you can see, I modified the WHERE clause and used `l.location_id` instead of your `d.department_id`. Why?

- because substitution variable suggests so (`&EnterLocID`) - location ID, not department ID
- if it was really `d.department_id`, then why are you joining `locations` and `departments` in the first place? Omit `locations`  table if you don't need it.

Finally, why `decode`? If you joined these two tables, then you have everything you need, i.e. something like this should do it:

```
select l.location_name
into v_dep
from locations l join departments d on d.location_id = l.location_id
where l.location_id = v_user_input
```

Or, if it has to be decode for some reason (educational?), then

```
SELECT DECODE (v_User_Input,
               10, 'Seattle',
               20, 'Toronto',
               30, 'Toronto',
               40, 'London',
               50, 'South San Francisco',
               60, 'Southlake',
               70, 'Munich',
               80, 'Oxford',
               90, 'Toronto',
               'else')
  INTO v_dep
  FROM ldepartments d
 WHERE d.department_id = v_user_input
```

Comment: Thank you So much

This Is For Educational Reason and exactly right answer 

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Actually I dont Have Permission and Now I did that